# Missing module tensorflow on iPython azure machine learning (Classic)

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, tensorflow, azure-machine-learning-service

Yesterday I have install tensorflow module from iPython notebook from Azure machine learning studio (classic) version. The import worked well after installing the module using (!pip install tensorflow). But today when tried to import this module got this "missing module" error and when I tried reinstalling the module it works well. Am I missing anything here? 
Do I need to install the module each and everyday, before using it? Can someone please explain?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Azure Machine Learning (Classic) Studio notebooks, you need to install Tensorflow. Furthermore, the notebook server session times out after a period of inactivity, hence, you need to re-install Tensorflow once the server shuts down or after starting a new session. Thanks.

Here are some references:

https://notebooks.azure.com/help/jupyter-notebooks/timeouts

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notebooks/install-packages-jupyter-notebook